# Atomic operations in ARM strex and ldrex - can they work on I/O registers?

Tags: thread-safety, arm, atomic

Suppose I'm modifying a few bits in a memory-mapped I/O register, and it's possible that another process or and ISR could be modifying other bits in the same register.

Can ldrex and strex be used to protect against this? I mean, they can in principle because you can ldrex, and then change the bit(s), and strex it back, and if the strex fails it means another operation may have changed the reg and you have to start again. But can the strex/ldrex mechanism be used on a non-cacheable area?

I have tried this on raspberry pi, with an I/O register mapped into userspace, and the ldrex operation gives me a bus error. If I change the ldrex/strex to a simple ldr/str it works fine (but is not atomic any more...) Also, the ldrex/strex routines work fine on ordinary RAM. Pointer is 32-bit aligned.

So is this a limitation of the strex/ldrex mechanism? or a problem with the BCM2708 implementation, or the way the kernel has set it up? (or somethinge else- maybe I've mapped it wrong)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thanks for mentioning me...

You do not use ldrex/strex pairs on the resource itself.  Like swp or test and set or whatever your instruction set supports (for arm it is swp and more recently strex/ldrex).  You use these instructions on ram, some ram location agreed to by all the parties involved.  The processes sharing the resource use the ram location to fight over control of the resource, whoever wins, gets to then actually address the resource.  You would never use swp or ldrex/strex on a peripheral itself, that makes no sense.  and I could see the memory system not giving you an exclusive okay response (EXOKAY) which is what you need to get out of the ldrex/strex infinite loop.

You have two basic methods for sharing a resource (well maybe more, but here are two).  One is you use this shared memory location and each user of the shared resource, fights to win control over the memory location.  When you win you then talk to the resource directly.  When finished give up control over the shared memory location.

The other method is you have only one piece of software allowed to talk to the peripheral, nobody else is allowed to ever talk to the peripheral.  Anyone wishing to have something done on the peripheral asks the one resource to do it for them.  It is like everyone being able to share the soft drink fountain, vs the soft drink fountain is behind the counter and only the soft drink fountain employee is allowed to use the soft drink fountain.  Then you need a scheme either have folks stand in line or have folks take a number and be called to have their drink filled.  Along with the single resource talking to the peripheral you have to come up with a scheme, fifo for example, to essentially make the requests serial in nature.

These are both on the honor system.  You expect nobody else to talk to the peripheral who is not supposed to talk to the peripheral, or who has not won the right to talk to the peripheral.  If you are looking for hardware solutions to prevent folks from talking to it, well, use the mmu but now you need to manage the who won the lock and how do they get the mmu unblocked (without using the honor system) and re-blocked in a way that

Situations where you might have an interrupt handler and a foreground task sharing a resource, you have one or the other be the one that can touch the resource, and the other asks for requests.  for example the resource might be interrupt driven (a serial port for example) and you have the interrupt handlers talk to the serial port hardware directly, if the application/forground task wants to have something done it fills out a request (puts something in a fifo/buffer) the interrupt then looks to see if there is anything in the request queue, and if so operates on it.

Of course there is the, disable interrupts and re-enable critical sections, but those are scary if you want your interrupts to have some notion of timing/latency...Understand what you are doing and they can be used to solve this app+isr two user problem.

ldrex/strex on non-cached memory space:

My extest perhaps has more text on the when you can and cant use ldrex/strex, unfortunately the arm docs are not that good in this area.  They tell you to stop using swp, which implies you should use strex/ldrex.  But then switch to the hardware manual which says you dont have to support exclusive operations on a uniprocessor system.  Which says two things, ldrex/strex are meant for multiprocessor systems and meant for sharing resources between processors on a multiprocessor system.  Also this means that ldrex/strex is not necessarily supported on uniprocessor systems.  Then it gets worse.  ARM logic generally stops either at the edge of the processor core, the L1 cache is contained within this boundary it is not on the axi/amba bus.  Or if you purchased/use the L2 cache then the ARM logic stops at the edge of that layer.  Then you get into the chip vendor specific logic.  That is the logic that you read the hardware manual for where it says you dont NEED to support exclusive accesses on uniprocessor systems.  So the problem is vendor specific.  And it gets worse, ARM's L1 and L2 cache so far as I have found do support ldrex/strex, so if you have the caches on then ldrex/strex will work on a system whose vendor code does not support them.  If you dont have the cache on that is when you get into trouble on those systems (that is the extest thing I wrote).

The processors that have ldrex/strex are new enough to have a big bank of config registers accessed through copressor reads.  buried in there is a "swp instruction supported" bit to determine if you have a swap.  didnt the cortex-m3 folks run into the situation of no swap and no ldrex/strex?

The bug in the linux kernel (there are many others as well for other misunderstandings of arm hardware and documentation) is that on a processor that supports ldrex/strex the ldrex/strex solution is chosen without determining if it is multiprocessor, so you can (and I know of two instances) get into an infinite ldrex/strex loop.  If you modify the linux code so that it uses the swp solution (there is code there for either solution) they linux will work.  why only two people have talked about this on the internet that I know of, is because you have to turn off the caches to have it happen (so far as I know), and who would turn off both caches and try to run linux?  It actually takes a fair amount of work to succesfully turn off the caches, modifications to linux are required to get it to work without crashing.

No, I cant tell you the systems, and no I do not now nor ever have worked for ARM. This stuff is all in the arm documentation if you know where to look and how to interpret it.

Comment: I'm aware of such mechanisms, but these require an agreed-on mechanism and a location for the lock variable. In this situation we have usermode apps fiddling directly with GPIO pin modes, hoping that they don't collide with other operations doing that too. And it doesn't need to be as sophisticated as ldrex/strex - it would be adequate to simply disable interrupts for an atomic update - but, usermode so I can't. If there was a 'compare and swap' (ala 68k)  instruction that would work too.

Comment: And it's perfectly reasonable for you to say "Uh, don't do that, use/write a device driver". I do get that. I'm just saying it would be nice to be able to do this otherwise because (1) it's less hassle if you don't have to write a driver (2) if there is a driver to switch pin modes, what happens when I want to bit-bash an 'open collector' driver, which means switching pin mode from input to output and back at high rates; using a driver will limit the speed a lot. Since I've done this on other systems in the past (e.g. with CAS) I was wondering if the same was possible here.

Comment: I guess what I'm saying is, "when I write a hack for direct I/O, is there some way I can at least make it a *thread-safe* hack?" Because I've certainly been able to do that in other situations (mostly embedded RTOS). Thanks for the answer.

Comment: arm has a swap instruction, swp.

Comment: strex performs an str on the memory location (or should), ldrex performs an ldr from the memory location (or should).  You simply have to test on a vendor by vendor and chip by chip basis if they happen to support exclusive access and beyond that exclusive access on the address space you are interested in.

Comment: thank you, I looked into that. SWP is OK for mutexes, but I don't think it's right for this situation; at best you could look at the read result to see what you'd broken, and then 'unbreak' it and hope for the best. Some processors have a 'compare and swap' where it only performs the write if the read value matches a given value; that would be great for this issue.

Comment: And for this situation, I really just need the strex to fail if there has been a context switch since the ldrex (this is a subset of what it does overall) since there's only one core.

Comment: @dwelch Where did you get the information that LDREX / STREX are for multiprocessor systems? The docs I've read about the topic suggest that they are perfectly fine on, eg. a Cortex-M3 or Cortex-M4.

Comment: from arm documentation that predated the cortex-m3/m4.  folks have been using them for a replacement for swap rather than for synchronizing exclusive access...one thing leads to another.

Comment: Why shouldn't one use LDREX/STREX on I/O registers directly?  If several pieces of independently-developed code code all use LDREX/STREX to manipulate distinct sets of bits in an I/O register, they will operate without conflict even if none of them know anything about the others.  By contrast, code which tries to use an outside flag to guard an I/O resource can only coexist with other code that uses *the same flag*.

Comment: ldrex/strex relies on the logic behind it to work.  once you get outside arms logic, which works so far as I have seen, you are in the chip vendors logic where the arm docs for uniprocessor say you dont have to support it.   and that would be for ram, for peripherals could be the same logic path or further in.  Or the implementation could be to just return EXOKAY and not actually check...As a general rule you would have to have intimate knowledge of every chip implementation from every vendor to know whether or not to use the pair as a habit.  which you wouldnt so dont use the par as a habit

Comment: only where it would/should explicitly work (multicore arm cores), and in that case one would hope the whole address space is covered.  For the cortex-ms I want to say the docs say that they just answer EXOKAY and not actually check but would have to re-read that...

Answer (score 5):

Generally, the `ldrex` and `strex` need support from the memory systems.  You may wish to refer to [some answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11383125/do-the-arm-instructions-ldrex-strex-have-to-operate-on-cache-aligned-data) by *dwelch* as well as his [extext](https://github.com/dwelch67/raspberrypi/tree/master/extest) application.  I would believe that you can not do this for *memory mapped I/O*.  `ldrex` and `strex` are intended more for [Lock Free](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-blocking_algorithm) algorithms, in *normal* memory.

Generally only one driver should be *in charge* of a bank of **I/O** registers.  Software will make requests to that driver via semaphores, etc which can be implement with `ldrex` and `strex` in normal SDRAM.  So, you can inter-lock these **I/O** registers, but not in the direct sense.

Often, the I/O registers will support *atomic* access through **write one to clear**, **multiplexed access** and other schemes.

1. **Write one to clear** - typically use with hardware events.  If code handles the event, then it writes only that bit.  In this way, multiple routines can handle different bits in the same register.
2. **Multiplexed access** - often an *interrupt enable/disable* will have a register bitmap.  However, there are also alternate register that you can write the interrupt number to which *enable* or *disable* a particular register.  For instance, `intmask` maybe two 32 bit registers.  To enable `int3`, you could mask `1<<3` to the `intmask` or write only `3` to an `intenable` register.  They `intmask` and `intenable` are hooked to the same bits via hardware.

So, you can emulate an inter-lock with a driver or the hardware itself may support atomic operations through normal register writes.  These schemes have served systems well for quiet some time before people even started to talk about **lock free** and **wait free** algorithms.

Comment: yes, the BCM2708 has a mechanism allowing individual I/O pins to be set high or low safely (with a single write). But the I/O pin *mode* bits (input vs. output etc) are packed several into a control register, and different pins can be for otherwise unrelated functions. I'll look into whether there is a driver mechanism to safely change them. A lot of folks are programming I/O in userspace on the raspberry pi, by mapping the GPIO registers, and the pin mode changes are generally not done safely...

Comment: In fact, since there's only one core, we only need to guard against interrupts (other processes or ISR changing modes of other pins) so all that's needed here is the ldrex/strex mechanism to invalidate the exclusivity on a context switch. But if it doesn't support non-memory address ranges, then it's not the solution.

Comment: On Linux, there is a GPIO driver which usually takes care of this.  Most of the time, input/output is not done on the fly, but you can end up doing this when bit bashing some protocols.  You can *shadow* the input/output register with `ldrex` and `strex` and then always *write* that location to the actual hardware.

Comment: Actually, there's still a hazard there - if you load a shadow value to write it, then someone else comes in, changes the shadow, writes it out, then you get control back and store your (stale) value to the register. The shadow variable is fine but the actual register has done something broken. So you'd still need to do the shadow->reg copy only in contexts that can't interrupt each other.

Comment: That is true.  I guess if you are really worried, you can mask interrupts, etc.  Usually there is only one driver toggling input to output (simulating 1wire, i2c, etc).  Most values are set at boot and never changed.

Comment: As others have pointed out, the `ldrx` and `strx`  instructions are a high performance mechanism for implementing atomic access to memory *that relies on the co-operation of the cache controller* on each core.   Memory mapped IO should *never* be cachable in the first place.

Comment: It would be nice if hardware designers gave consistent thought to issues surrounding concurrency, rather than e.g. having write-one-to-clear values share addresses with latched values.  I wonder why so few parts allow one to e.g. switch the direction of some bits on a port while leaving others unaffected.  It should be very cheap in hardware [omit two address bits (e.g. A2-A3) from the decode logic for the DDR, and then have each bit Rn compute (Rn & (!A2 | Dn)) | (A3 & Dn).  Address 01xx will clear any bits written as zeroes; 10xx will set any bits written as ones, and 11xx will do both.

Comment: To my mind, in a well-designed part, it should be possible to perform any desired action on any peripheral without having to worry about the state of any other peripheral.  Not only does such ability simplify user code, but it also makes it possible to mix and match routines from different sources without having to worry about them interfering.  It saddens me that some companies spend a lot of money on development systems to let people configure hardware and auto-generate driver code with graphical tools, but have hardware share registers among peripherals in awkward ways.

Comment: @greggo I think you are wrong about the *race*.  The person writing to the shadow value would also have to grab the exclusive lock.  After re-reading these answers, [unix smurf](http://stackoverflow.com/users/563188/unixsmurf) has some good information.

Comment: @artlessnoise  An exclusive lock takes care of that, but what I meant to point out is that you can't release that lock until after you've written the shadow reg AND the real reg. Exclusivity on the shadow reg alone is not enough. So at this point you don't really need the shadow register, you could do the same lock on the register proper. It would also work with lock[ modify_shadow()] followed by lock [ reg := shadow ] with no lock between .. but that second copy op has to re-read the shared 'shadow' var.

Comment: I think we had a disconnect.  The shadow register would be written from user space for example.  A kernel space would write with some fixed latency to the actual hardware.  So there is no need to lock the actual hardware.  It works for some cases, for instance a bank of LEDs where several tasks/threads want to set an individual LED, the hardware synchronization thread would update them at some latency.  In fact this can be more performant as often the hardware has long access cycles compared to DDR, cache, etc.

Answer (score 4):

Like previous answers state, `ldrex`/`strex` are not intended for accessing the resource itself, but rather for implementing the synchronization primitives required to protect it.

However, I feel the need to expand a bit on the architectural bits:

1. `ldrex`/`strex` (pronounced load-exclusive/store-exclusive) are supported by **all** ARM architecture version 6 and later processors, minus the M0/M1 microcontrollers (ARMv6-M).
2. It is not architecturally guaranteed that load-exclusive/store-exclusive will work on memory types other than "Normal" - so any clever usage of them on peripherals would not be portable.
3. The `SWP` instruction isn't being recommended against simply because its very nature is counterproductive in a multi-core system - it was deprecated in ARMv6 and is "optional" to implement in certain ARMv7-A revisions, and most ARMv7-A processors already require it to be explicitly enabled in the cp15 `SCTLR`. Linux by default does not, and instead emulates the operation through the undef handler using ... load-exclusive and store-exclusive (what @dwelch refers to above). So please don't recommend SWP as a valid alternative if you are expecting code to be portable across ARMv7-A platforms.

Synchronization with bus masters not in the inner-shareable domain (your cache-coherency island, as it were) requires additional external hardware - referred to as a *global monitor* - in order to track which masters have requested exclusive access to which regions.

The "not required on uniprocessor systems" bit sounds like the ARM terminology getting in the way. A quad-core Cortex-A15 is considered one processor... So testing for "uniprocessor" in Linux would not make one iota of a difference - the architecture and the interconnect specifications remain the same regardless, and SWP is still optional and may not be present at all.

Cortex-M3 supports ldrex/strex, but its interconnect (AHB-lite) does not support propagating it, so it cannot use it to synchronize with external masters. It does not support SWP, never introduced in the Thumb instruction set, which its interconnect would also not be able to propagate.

Answer (score 0):

If the chip in question has a toggle register (which is essentially XORed with the output latch when written to) there is a work around.

- load port latch
- mask off unrelated bits
- xor with desired output
- write to toggle register

as long as two processes do not modify the same pins (as opposed to "the same port") there is no race condition.

In the case of the bcm2708 you could choose an output pin whose neighbors are either unused or are never changed and write to GPFSELn in byte mode. This will however only ensure that you will not corrupt others. If others are writing in 32 bit mode and you interrupt them they will still corrupt you. So its kind of a hack.

Hope this helps

Comment: Yes indeed, and the broadcom chip in the RPi has these for the GPIO output pin states. Not, however, for registers which set input vs. output. If you want an 'open-collector' output, you need to toggle between output-0 and 'input' --  which involves changing regs that don't have a toggle feature. Which is how I got here, last year...

Comment: Ah ok sorry, I'm not a RPi guy.