# Atomic compare and exchange in arm assembly

Tags: linux, assembly, arm

I am trying to compile the arm inline assembly code for ARMV7 to compare and swap  atomically, basically i have copied the code from ARM linux kernel but somehow it doesnt compile. it gives the below error

Erro: thumb conditional instruction should be in IT block -- `strexeq r5,r1,[r3]`. below is the code

```
static inline int
dfp_atomic32_cmpset(volatile uint32_t *dst, uint32_t exp, uint32_t src)
{

        unsigned long oldval, res;

        smp_mb();

        do {
                __asm__ __volatile__("@ dfp_atomic32_cmpset\n"
                "ldrex  %1, [%3]\n"
                "mov    %0, #0\n"
                "teq    %1, %4\n"
                "strexeq %0, %5, [%3]\n"
                    : "=&r" (res), "=&r" (oldval), "+Qo" (*dst)
                    : "r" (dst), "Ir" (exp), "r" (src)
                    : "cc");
        } while (res);

        smp_mb();

        return oldval;
}
```

Any idea what that error means?

Comment: yes, i figured that out but instead of IT EQ, i am using a cheat at the gcc assembler level. i.e. Wa,-mimplicit-it=always, do you see any problem with this other than compatibility ?

Comment: Actually i figured out the answer after i posted the question, i was in bit hurry to find out the answer ;-). Error is due to "In Thumb-2, most instructions to not have a built in condition code (except for conditional branches). Instead, short sequences of instructions which are to be executed conditionally can be preceded by a special "IT instruction"" This site explains it well https://wiki.ubuntu.com/ARM/Thumb2PortingHowto#Types . BTW i still would like to accept your answer, let me figure out how to accept ;-)

Comment: I know I sound like a broken record with this, but...ARM quite clearly states that chip vendors do not have to support the exclusive access (strex/ldrex).  Linux quite often gets ARM details wrong in particular uses the wrong atomic (strex/ldrex vs swp) as a general rule.  Just beware of this, esp if you are changing chips.

Comment: @dwelch: i am looking for fast atomic operation to build highly optimized multithread safe library, definitely its a trade off between performance and portability.

Comment: Sure, that is fine, strex/ldrex are for exclusive access to shared memory ranges in a multi-core arm chip.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add an `IT EQ` instruction; see [Thumb2 porting](https://wiki.edubuntu.org/ARM/Thumb2PortingHowto#Conditional_Execution) at the **Ubuntu wiki**. You are copying **ARM** code and trying to use it in **thumb2** mode. All **ARM** instructions are conditional and the `IT EQ` is a phantom in **ARM** mode (not needed). In **Thumb2** mode, you have to notify the process which condition should be tested for the following instructions.

It is possible that *gcc inlines* do not apply to `-mimplicit-it`; especially as the compiler needs to guess the number of op-codes to make it's own code.  Ie, to calculate branch sizes, etc.

Comment: [strex/ldrex to i/o registers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15995340/atomic-operations-in-arm-strex-and-ldrex-can-they-work-on-i-o-registers/16032047#16032047) has some good information on the title of this question, which is a little misleading as the question is really about **ARM/Thumb2** assembler compatibility.