# How can I implement Read/Modify/Write for Microcomputer Peripheral Registers without Bitbanding?

Tags: c, assembly, arm, embedded, cortex-m

I want to know how to implement Read/Modify/Write againt Microcomputer Peripheral Register.
For example, UART control and status register.
When I turn off UART interrupt enable flag,  I read/modify/write register.
but, between read and modify, if interrupt status flag turn on, status flag is turned off.
I use Cortex-m3 without Bitband.
If bitband exists, AHB bus is locked. While bus is locked, Peripheral do not update register.
So, Read/Modify/Write is easily implemented.

I think that LDREX,STREX is used for read/modify/write.
After LDREX register address, If register is updated by peripheral, STREX return failure ?

I expect that peripheral notify updating register against AHB bus.
So when core execute STRED, AHB return failure status.

Comment: You can't use ldrex/strex on peripherals, only RAM.  You need to use some kind of critical section.  If you use an RTOS then use a mutex.  If you use bare metal, you can implement something like a mutex with ldrex/strex on a RAM location.  Alternatively many microcontrollers implement a way of doing this in hardware that is specific to the GPIO, eg: BSRR in STM32.  Which hardware are you using?

Comment: ldrex/strex is for multi core sharing, on some of the mcus they are implemented as ldr/str for code compatibility.   Please show your code, I have a feeling I know what you are doing and it is not a read-modify-write.  bitbanding, exclusive access, etc are not required for read-modify-write just an ldr, some code and an str and can be done on any register or memory.

Comment: ldrex/strex could be used if you are sharing this register between cores to control who has access to the resource, but that would beg to understand the system design and why are you sharing a register/peripheral across cores instead of an abstraction/driver where one core owns the peripheral and all others put in requests?

Comment: hmm we need a complete example here, your comments and questions do not make sense as a whole, seems like you have a number of moving parts here and are not explaining the whole software system setup.  which is likely the problem, trying to hack at something perhaps without understanding the system effects.

Comment: `ldrex/strex` can be used for single cores.  However, the important point is that it **ONLY** applies to cores.  An interrupt controller does not obey `ldrex/strex`.  There is [a duplicate of this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15995340/atomic-operations-in-arm-strex-and-ldrex-can-they-work-on-i-o-registers); although it is multiple cores using an I/O address (this case is even more restrictive).  I will close it instantly, if I mark it as such.  Please try to update your question.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.